# Monolog Couldn't find constant Monolog\Logger::DEBUGS

Tags: symfony, composer-php, monolog

I keep getting an error with the MonologBundle for Symfony2:

```
Monolog\Logger::DEBUGS in /foo/vendor/symfony/monolog-bundle/Symfony/Bundle/MonologBundle/DependencyInjection/MonologExtension.php on line 119
```

It only happens in prod and happens only once, right after deleting the cache. After a refresh everything is back to normal.

All other answers suggest updating composer, which I have done, or deleting the bundle and monolog and reinstalling, which I have also done.

It happens both on my local machine (mac) and during deployment to my ubuntu machine using capistrano 2.x with capifony. Composer is freshly downloaded during those deploys, so composer version probably isn't the issue here.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you have a typo in config, where you defined a log level for one of your handlers as "debugs" instead of "debug". Check your config.